# Batch file to delete specific text file from multiple locations

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file written that creates a text file within each sub-folder of the root folder that displays the sub-folder's contents. The issue I'm having now is creating a second .bat that will remove said text files from the sub-folder locations. The .bat I have for creating the .txt files are located below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
@echo off
IF EXIST "R:\Projects\000" PUSHD "R:\Projects\000\" 
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /a:d-s-h /b') do ( 
     dir /s/b > R:\Projects\000\%%G\Folder_Contents.txt
)
POPD
```

Comment: It looks like the formatting in your question hasn't worked quite properly, could you take a look at it? I think the ">" are part of what you want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nearly the same as your current script.

**delAllFolderContent.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST "R:\Projects\000" (
  PUSHD "R:\Projects\000"
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /a:d-s-h /b') DO ( 
      DEL "R:\Projects\000\%%G\Folder_Contents.txt"
  )
  POPD
)
```

I moved the `FOR/F` code into the `IF EXIST` block, so it will be executed only when the directory exists and not always.

Answer (score 1):

If i truly understand you. It's look like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST "C:\Temp\" PUSHD "C:\Temp\"
ECHO @ECHO OFF > loc.bat 

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /a:d-s-h /b') DO ( 
  DIR /s/b > C:\Temp\%%G\Folder_Contents.txt 
  ECHO DEL C:\Temp\%%G\Folder_Contents.txt >> loc.bat
) 
POPD
```

Comment: +1, I think you got one solution, but I'm not sure if the OP wants dynamically create the second batch file

Answer (score 1):

```
del "R:\Projects\000\folder_contents.txt" /s
```

Comment: You missed the `\%%G\` part in the directory name

Comment: Why is it needed ? If all folder_contents.txt files are generated below 000 folder, /S in del will remove then recursively.

Comment: +1 Wow, you are right! I didn't know that `DEL` really split the path and look in each subdirectory for the filename. It seems to be the best/simplest solution here